# "I'm not understand" — help regarding sentence structure

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am trying to learn/improve my English by remembering grammar rules. Every day, I read a lot of technical documentation and have many conversations with my colleagues from US.

I already have many phrase templates, but sometimes I urge myself to stop using this and try to figure out the rules by which a phrase was constructed.

So, how common is the usage of the sentence "I'm not understand". (*Understand* — is a verb in 1st form used after form of *be*.)

What rules were used?
Why doesn't it sound like "I don't understand" or "I'm not understanding"?

Comment: Where did you see "I'm not understand?"

Comment: Best wishes learning English!  There's also a community at [http://ell.stackexchange.com/](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) that might be of interest to you in your endeavor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase "I'm not understand" is constructed... well... badly. It's simply incorrect.

Your two alternatives are correct. You can use *do understand* or *is understanding*, but you can't use *do understanding* or *is understand*. You use *do* with the verb in base form, and *is* with the verb in present participle form.

Comment: I just was confused by tons of google's result. Thanks.

Comment: For extra clarity: "I'm not understanding" would also be incorrect as a complete sentence to indicate that you don't understand something; normally you would always say "I don't understand".

Answer (score 3):

"I'm not understand." is not proper usage. A native speaker would never say it.

Comment: I just was confused by tons of google's result. Thanks.

Comment: Internet culture includes a tendency to deliberately mangle English grammar, as a form of wordplay.  (The paragon exemplar of this is of course lolcat speech, e.g. "*I can has cheezburger?")

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that "understand" is a verb, but you are using it as the sentence object, which must be a noun.

Use the noun "understanding" and it makes sense ("I am not understanding").

If you really want to use the *verb* "understand", use present perfect ("I do not understand")

Comment: It must be an adjective or a noun. Remember that *to be* is a copula.